# Send all journal logs to server

Tags: logging, embedded-linux, journal, systemd-journald, systemd-journal-remote

I can view journal logs with `journalctl`

How can I configure that all this log will send to my simple TCP server? I didn't find any configuration in `journald.conf`

Comment: How about forwarding them to a syslog daemon, and from there, forwarding to a remote host?

Comment: Also take a look at  systemd-journal-upload.service(8) and systemd-journal-remote.service(8). I haven't used them, but looks like they fit your purpose.